# Is it possible to use a broadcast inside a Spark partitioner?

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose I have a custom Spark partitioner that, to operate, requires a fixed, very large collection, passed in this example to its constructor. The `getPartition` method uses this collection to return the partition number.

I'm thinking to wrap the collection in a `Broadcast` variable, and pass the `Broadcast` to my custom partitioner constructor. Can a `Broadcast` be used outside of the typical functions passed to RDD methods like `map` and `filter`? Is its behavior well defined in this case? Is it guaranteed that the variable is transferred and shared efficiently among worker nodes JVMs?

Does it make any sense or it doesn't improve anything compared to just letting Spark capture the collection the standard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use broadcast variable from a `Paritioner`. However if `Partitioner` is not reused, the value of broadcasting might be minimal.

One way or another, there is no correctness issue here whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I also verified this possibility by myself, and the `Broadcast` mechanism works also outside of functions passed to `map`, `filter` and other `RDD` methods. From the logs it's clearly visible that the broadcast mechanism works, and the `Partitioner`, in this case, behaves as expected.

However, I think it's an overkill (for my case) and won't help unless the broadcasted object is reused in multiple places.